# Duplicating rows according to field values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, features, geopackage, duplication

I have a table in a GeoPackage like this

```
field1  field2
a;b          1
a;b          2
c;d          3
a;d;e        4
a            5
...
```

What I need is to create a new table in which the records are duplicated based on the values in `"field1"`. Like this

```
field1  field2
a            1
b            1
a            2
b            2
c            3
d            3
a            4
d            4
e            4
a            5
...
```

Does anyone know a tool, function, expression or any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume there is a polyline layer called *'lines'* with three features in it, see the image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Duplicate geometries as many times as needed by means of the ["Array of translated features"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgisarraytranslatedfeatures) algorithm and the following expression in *'Number of features to create'*:

```
array_length(string_to_array("dupl", ';')) - 1
```

[image: step1]

**Step 2.** Get the unique values for each feature in the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and this expression:

```
array_get(string_to_array("dupl", ';'), "instance")
```

[image: step2]

Comment: It works perfect. Thanks @Taras.

Comment: I just do not know if you need duplicated features too, do you?

Answer (score 4):

**The *SQLite* way, for reference:**

Unfortunately, *SQLite* neither supports arrays natively, nor their unnesting into sets of rows. The only, recommended yet slightly cumbersome way is a `RECURSIVE` *CTE*:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  unnest(val, arr_el, _arr_res) AS (
    SELECT
      val,
      '',
      arr || ';'
    FROM
      nested_arr
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      val,
      SUBSTR(_arr_res, 0, INSTR(_arr_res, ';')),
      SUBSTR(_arr_res, INSTR(_arr_res, ';') + 1)
    FROM
      unnest
    WHERE
      _arr_res <> ''
  )
SELECT
  arr_el, val
FROM
  unnest
WHERE
  arr_el <> ''
ORDER BY
  val, arr_el
;
```

***[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rU_hf6FQ)***