# Unesting JSON array in SQLite

Tags: qgis, json, sqlite, array

I'm using DB Manager on QGIS to write a view. I want to *"translate"* `unnest()` SQL function, but I don't find the same in SQLite.

**SQL**

```sql
SELECT unnest(ARRAY['A','B','C']);
```

| unnest |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

[The documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) describes two aggregate functions and two table-valued functions. I tried [`json_each`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach), which returns a row for each `json` value but I can't display unnested values.

**SQLite**

```sql
SELECT myfield
FROM my_table, json_each(my_field);
```

| my_field |
| --- |
| ["A", "B", "C" ] |
| ["A", "B", "C" ] |
| ["A", "B", "C" ] |

How to easily unnest `json` elements in SQLite?

Comment: Only way is a recursive CTE: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/460107/93656

Comment: In `SQLite` there is no such function: unnest

Comment: If you are referring to the `unnest` in my linked answer, that's not a function but a virtual table name of the recursive CTE expresion that mimics an unnest. However, you may want to try the `json_tree` variant to also walk children. If that doesn't unnest the array values of your JSON, you have to use the recursive CTE as in my linked answer. And you will have to use the recursive CTE if your array is not a valid JSON in the first place...

Comment: Ok, understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [json_each function](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach) returns the desired values in the `value` column:

```
create table my_table(id, myfield);
insert into my_table values (1, '["A","B","C"]'), (2, '["X"]');

SELECT my_table.id, j.value
FROM my_table, json_each(myfield) j;
```

```
id | value
----------
1  | A
1  | B
1  | C
2  | X
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

As @geozelot suggests, the only way I found is a recursive CTE.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  unnest(val, arr_el, _arr_res) AS (
    SELECT
      myfield,
      '',
      myfield || ','
    FROM
      my_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      val,
      SUBSTR(_arr_res, 0, INSTR(_arr_res, ',')),
      SUBSTR(_arr_res, INSTR(_arr_res, ',') + 1)
    FROM
      unnest
    WHERE
      _arr_res <> ''
  )
SELECT
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(arr_el, '[', ''), ']', ''), '"', '') AS arr_el,
  val
FROM
  unnest
WHERE
  arr_el <> ''
ORDER BY
  val, arr_el
;
```

Really heavy to manipulate, I'm surprised there are aggregates functions and no easy way to disaggregate.